# Finding prime numbers by Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm(C++)

Tags: c++, sieve-of-eratosthenes

I want to create a function that finds all prime numbers until number `num` based on the ([Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)) algorithm

Here is my code:

```
vector<int> prime(double num){

    vector<int> check;
    vector<int> prime;
    if(num < 2) throw "Number must be bigger than or equal to 2!";
    for(int i = 0; i<num;++i){
        check.push_back(1);
    }
    for(double i = 2;i<sqrt(num);++i){
        int k = 1;
        if(check.at(i) == true){
            for(double j = pow(i,2); j<num; j = j+k*i){
                check[j] = 0;
                prime.push_back(j);
                ++k;
            }
        }
    }
    return prime;
}


int main(){
    int num;
    vector<int> v;
    cout << "Enter number n bigger than 1:";
    cin >> num;
    v = prime(num);
    for(int i;i<v.size();++i){
        cout << v[i];
    }
}
```

I checked code by parts and everything works as it should work, except this part:

```
for(double i = 2;i<sqrt(num);++i){
    int k = 1;
    if(check.at(i) == true){
        for(double j = pow(i,2); j<num; j = j+k*i){
            check[j] = 0;
            prime.push_back(j);
            ++k;
        }
    }
}
```

There is no error in the code, but there is no output and I cannot understand why.

Comment: Don't use floating point anywhere when solving whole number (integer) problems.

Comment: Aside: `x == true` is entirely equivalent to `x` in a boolean context

Comment: @Caleth but I do check[j] = 0 and I suppose it should make some coefficients equal to 0. Am i right?

Comment: Why do you push every j onto prime?

Comment: There may be other problems with your code, but I see `for(int i;i<v.size();++i)` should init `i=0`

Comment: @Jay  here check[j] = 0; I set coefficients to 0, and other coefficients, that are non-zero are prime numbers

Comment: or just be `for (int i : v) { std::cout << i; }`

Comment: I don't think it's doing what you think it's doing. Try and fix your output bug and have a look at stepping though your code. Where it checks those values is outside of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

The innermost loop `for(double j = pow(i,2); j<num; j = j+k*i)` is rather suspect.

You only want to increase `j` by `i` each iteration, but instead you are increasing it by some multiple of `i`.

You also shouldn't be adding all the `j`s to `prime`, they are by construction all composite. Instead add `i`.

Because `for` loops check the condition before they run, you don't need to `throw` for num < 2, you can just return an empty vector (there are no primes less than 2)

rather than doing an integer problem in `double`, you can use `int` throughout.

```
vector<int> prime(int num){
    vector<bool> check(num, true); // num copies of true
    vector<int> prime;
    for(int i = 2; i < num; ++i){
        if(check[i]){
            prime.push_back(i);
            for(int j = i*i; j < num; j += i){
                check[j] = false;
            }
        }
    }
    return prime;
}


int main(){
    cout << "Enter number n bigger than 1:";
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    vector<int> v = prime(num);
    for(int i : v){
        cout << i;
    }
}
```